# How to convert MongoDB object that contains array of key-value pairs into one concatenated string?

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I am working with MongoDB using some Python and its module pymongo. I have a small issue that I need to solve: Here is my simple aggregation method that I use with mongodb and below it's output for the 'Data' object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
        '$project': {       
            'Id': '$ResultData.Id',
            'Data' : '$Results.Data',
        }
 }])


'Data': [{'key': 'a', 'value': 'true'},
  {'key': 'number1', 'value': '4235'},
  {'key': 'Name','value': '3M'},
  {'key': 'message', 'value': 'some text'},
  {'key': 'city', 'value': 'London'},
  {'key': 'street', 'value': 'times 22'},
  {'key': 'code', 'value': '123'}],
```

I want to change my output in the way that I will have all keys and values in the string in format:

```
key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value,key=value
```

On the given example:

```
'Data' : 'a=true;number1=4235;Name=3M;message=some text;city=London;street=times 22;code=123'
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of results in MongoDB?

Comment: You can use the Aggregation array operator [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to get the desired result.

Comment: Than you for an answer. I am trying to do that. Can you give me a few more clues how to do that?

Comment: `$reduce` iterates over the array. So, for each array element build a string with concatenated values of fields `key` and `value`. And, append it to the `initialValue` (of `$reduce`) - which would be an empty string to start with. By the end of the iteration of the complete array, you will have one string, the result.

Comment: I am using `{'$reduce': {
        'input': '$Results.Data',
        'initialValue': '',
        'in': { '$concat' : ["$$value", "$$this.value"]}}}` 
And I have in output concat all of the values, just don't know how to add key and = sign

Comment: `$concat: ["$$this.key", "=", "$$this.value", "$$value"]`

Comment: Thank you I have my output with `["$$value","$$this.key", "=", "$$this.value",';']`